# Doing a roll-in/roll-out slideshow in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, slideshow

I am trying to create a roll-in / roll-out slideshow in jQuery/JavaScript.
My problem is, that it needs to be repeated. And right now when it's starting over, the pictures doesnt come from the right side anymore :(

The reason for which I have created the slideLeft function, is that afterwards I need to create 2 functions, where the user can interrupt the slideshow manually pressing a left or right button.

This is what I've got:

```
<script class="jsbin" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<div style='background: #c4c4c4; border: 1px solid #7b7b7b; height: 220px; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px; position: absolute; width: 590px;'>
  <div id='slider-image-1' style='left: 5px; background: red; height: 216px; padding: 2px; position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 586px;'></div>
  <div id='slider-image-2' style='left: 600px; background: yellow; height: 216px; padding: 2px; position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 586px;'></div>
  <div id='slider-image-3' style='left: 600px; background: green; height: 216px; padding: 2px; position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 586px;'></div>
  <div id='slider-image-4' style='left: 600px; background: blue; height: 216px; padding: 2px; position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 586px;'></div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var amount = 0;
    var nextamount = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
      amount++;
      nextamount++;
      if (nextamount === 5) nextamount = 1;
      if (amount === 5) amount = 1;
        slideLeft(amount, nextamount);
      }, 2000);
    });

  function slideLeft(i, j) {
    var $theItem = $('#slider-image-' + i);
    $theItem.animate({
      left: parseInt($theItem.css('left'), 10) == 5 ? -$theItem.outerWidth() : 5
    }, 500);

    var $theItem = $('#slider-image-' + j);
    $theItem.animate({
      left: parseInt($theItem.css('left'), 10) == 5 ? $theItem.outerWidth() + 10 : 5
    }, 500);

  };
</script>
```

Comment: If you are trying to learn jquery then ignore the rest of this comment.  There are some great plugins that can do all of this: next/prev, repitition, etc.  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html

Comment: I think this question might be too "localized," meaning it's only helpful for your project.  Can you trim the code down a bit to focus on a more general problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare element, which is going to roll in, to be on the right.

```
function slideLeft(i, j) {
  var $theItem = $('#slider-image-' + i);
  $theItem.animate({
    left: parseInt($theItem.css('left'), 10) == 5 ? -$theItem.outerWidth() : 5
  }, 500);

  var $theItem = $('#slider-image-' + j);
  $theItem.css('left', '600px'); // moves in item to the right before animation
  $theItem.animate({
    left: parseInt($theItem.css('left'), 10) == 5 ? $theItem.outerWidth() + 10 : 5
  }, 500);

};
```

I think you've tried it with your parseInt, but it doesn't work, so you can get rid of it.

```
function slideLeft(i, j) {
  var $outItem = $('#slider-image-' + i);
  $outItem.animate({ left: -$outItem.outerWidth() }, 500);

  var $inItem = $('#slider-image-' + j);
  $inItem.css('left', '600px');
  $inItem.animate({ left: 5 }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made something like this before, i dont know if this will help you, what i did was:
Add a copy of the first slide in the end of the collection of images/slides. Then, when you are showing the last "real" image and it will look like you are scrolling to the first image (but that is just a copy of the first image), and then when the animation is done you can position it with the default "left" css value. If you want it to scroll both ways, you can do the same with a copy of the last image/slide before the first image, but then you'll have to start the slider with a offset.

its a bit hard to explain, do you get the point? :)